# Digital circuit to toggle on rising edge of two signals

Tags: digital-logic

I need to design a circuit to toggle on the rising edge of two signals A and B. A is a square wave @10Hz, 50% duty cycle. B is a pulse that gets generated approx 20-30us after the rising edge of A. 
I came up with a circuit to achieve it, but it uses monoshots which I wish to avoid. The monoshot is triggered by the pulse and it's Q' as well as signal A are the inputs to an AND gate to generate the required output Y=A.B'
Can you suggest a better way which uses digital circuits only? Thanks.[image][image]

Comment: How accurate and consistent does the timing have to be? Would it be okay to have 5-100 ns of uncertainty about how long after the edges of A and B the output changes?

Comment: Also, are you doing this with discrete logic, in a CPLD, in an FPGA, or in an ASIC or full custom chip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a D flip-flop with an asyncronous clear function

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7r3Kl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Practically, you'll more often find the clear function has a low-active input, so you might need an inverter on your B signal.

For example, you could use [74AC11074](http://www.ti.com/product/74ac11074).